# Haskell average function

Tags: haskell

I'm not really sure where to start here.

I need to write an average function that uses a lambda expression and takes in a list of floats and returns the average as a float in haskell

So far I have

```
average [] = 0
average xs = foldr (\x xs -> x : xs) []
```

Comment: Question: why do you use `(\x xs -> x : xs)` here as `foldr` function? How would you - let us forget about Haskell for now - write an `average` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to write an average function that uses a lambda expression ...

I take that as you want to implement an `average` function using `foldr` and a lambda you write. Otherwise, (not considering performance issues) I would just write

```
average :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
average xs = sum xs / length xs
```

But maybe it's more important for you to figure out how to write things in Haskell than simply have that average function.

First, note the type signature of `average` above. As a general rule it's good to have the type in mind (and also in the code). `average` takes a bunch of numbers and return one number, thus the `(Num a) => [a] -> a`. If you stick to the type you'll find out what's wrong with your definition: `average xs = foldr (\x xs -> x : xs) []` would have type `[a] -> [a]`, so that wouldn't work anyway.

Then, as you've mentioned in the comment, you need to keep a running sum *and* a running counter and divide them to get the average. So you could just translate that into code:

```
sumAndCount :: (Num a) => [a] -> (a, Int)
sumAndCount xs = foldr (\x (s, c) -> (s + x, c + 1)) (0, 0) xs

average :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
average [] = error "Taking average of 0 numbers"
average xs = total / (fromIntegral counter) where
    (total, counter) = sumAndCount xs
```

Two small glitches:

- For mathematical consistency, it's better not to define average of `[]` as 0, because it actually should be `0/0` which is `NaN`. But you could do that if it's reasonable for your task.
- `fromIntegral` casts an integer to any `Num` type. That's necessary because division only works between the same type.

Apart from these, everything just happens naturally.

Comment: Was this code `average :: (Num a) => [a] -> a; average xs = sum xs / length xs`
supposed to work?

Because I am getting an error: `Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’; a’ is a rigid type variable bound by type signature for: average :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> a • In the second argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘length xs’`

So I have to replace (Num a ) with (Fractional  a) and add `fromIntegral` to `length` to make it compile.